# IN Query in Cassandra Where clause

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, scylla, cqlengine

I have a Scylla cluster with 3 Nodes and 1 Table created with the below Query

```
CREATE TABLE id_features (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    id_feature_1 int,
    id_feature_2 int,

)
```

I am issuing below query from the application
`SELECT * FROM  id_features where id in (1,2,3,4...120);`
The query can have a maximum of 120 ids.

Will this Query contact all 3 nodes based on the token value of id`s to fetch data for 120 ids in the worst case? 
Or only 1 node will be contacted to fetch the data for all the ids and multiple nodes are used only for high availability

Do the replication factor, consistency level, and load balancing policy will play any role in deciding the node?

Comment: @Aaron had a great answer, in addition to that; i think this blogpost is very useful to understand how reads are accomplished in different configurations and scenarios https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntClientRequestsRead.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will this Query contact all 3 nodes based on the token value of `id`s to fetch data
>
> Do the replication factor, consistency level, and load balancing policy will play any role in deciding the node?

It very much depends on things like replication factor (RF), query consistency, and load balancing policy.  Specifically, if RF < number of nodes, then multiple nodes will be contacted, based on the hashed token value of `id` and the nodes primarily assigned to those token ranges.

But, given this statement:

> Or only 1 node will be contacted to fetch the data for all the ids and multiple nodes are used only for high availability

...I get the sense that RF=3 in this case.

If the app is configured to use the (default) `TokenAwarePolicy` then yes, for single-key queries only, requests can be sent to the individual nodes.

But in this case, the query is using the `IN` operator.  Based on the 120 potential entries, the query *cannot* determine a single node to send the query.  In that case, the `TokenAwarePolicy` simply acts as a pass-through for its child policy (`DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy`), and it will pick a node at `LOCAL` distance to be the "coordinator."  The coordinator node will then take on the additional tasks of routing replica requests and compiling the result set.

As to whether or not non-primary replicas are utilized in query plans, the answer is again "it depends."  While the load balancing policies differ in implementation, in general all of them compute [query plans](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/#query-plan) which:

- are different for each query, in order to balance the load across the cluster;
- only contain hosts that are known to be able to process queries, i.e. neither ignored nor down;
- favor local hosts over remote ones.

*Taken from: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/#query-plan*

So in a scenario where RF = number of nodes, a single node *sometimes* may be used to return all requested replicas.

**Pro-tip**:

Try not to use the `IN` operator with a list of 120 partition key entries.  That is forcing Cassandra to perform *random* reads, where it really excels at *sequential reads*.  If that's a query the app really needs to do, try:

- Building a new table to better support that query pattern.
- Not exceed double-digits of entries for `IN`.

Comment: to add on to this - 120 separate async queries could be much faster. Overall, `IN` on partition key is not recommended

Comment: @AlexOtt absolutely!  Was waiting for a follow-up question to mention that, but this works!